# Is it possible to create P2P UDP Hole Punch with socket information from a TCP Socket?

Tags: c#, tcp, udp, nat, hole-punching

I am currently trying to implement a simple Hole Punch, and have a TCP Connection to a server, which sends the TCP Clients the endpoint information of one another. Can this information be used to create udp connections to punch a hole in the NAT and create a p2p connection using the UdpClient?

In my current approach i am using the standard .NET UdpClient to set all of this up. I set NatTraversal to true and set the ReuseAddress SocketOption to true aswell. Is it possible at all to create a successful connection with this udp client as it has not sent any information out to the server, making no route through the NAT.

```
    udpClient.AllowNatTraversal(true);
    udpClient.Client.SetIPProtectionLevel(IPProtectionLevel.Unrestricted);
    udpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
```

Comment: TCP, UDP, NAT are all different IP Protocols.  The Protocol Type is defined in the IP Header and c# has an enumeration for the Protocol Type (in the Net Library) that does not allow you to override.  So you have to either use c++ or use Windows dll methods (www.pinvoke.net) and call the windows library directly.  Nat is described at Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, but take a look at STUN.  That TCP connection to a server could be to a STUN server that could help provide enough information to determine how to punch holes so that the peers can communicate with UDP for certain NAT mechanisms.